# Do I have to use next.js Html component or is plain html okay to use in _document.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I was reading the [next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) and read that

> Html, Head, Main and NextScript are required for the page to be properly rendered.

We have been using a simple `<html lang="en">` tag in our _document.js for years and haven't seen any negative effects. Is there an advantage to using Next's `Html` element in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using `<html lang="en">` too without any side effects.
If the only thing you have to do is adding `lang` then using one or the other won't change anything.

On the other hand, if you need to add more complex logic the only option is to extend `<Html>` since is a class.

```
export class MyHtml extends Html {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    );
  }
}
```

Is still preferable `<Html>` though since it's provided by Next and we might not know what's going on under the hood.

Hope this helps.